# Autoplay is not working with option autoplay=1

Tags: youtube-api

As a part of our requirement, I am invoking search for videos (say search topic 'two cats') from my code in YouTube and require to play the first video displayed. I am currently using URL `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=two+cats` to search for videos. So, do we have an option to play the first video displayed?

Also, I tried invoking embedded URL `https://www.youtube.com/embed/OT1wEiOdGOI?autoplay=1` and found that the autoplay never works.

Can anyone help me resolve both of these issues?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then when you edit your question be sure to incldue a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

autoplay is working (only desktop browsers) but not on tablets or phones as a default behaviour

Comment: We are trying the above mentioned link in Desktop browser only. But still we observe that it is not working.